# my full array isn't being displayed

Tags: c#, arrays, display

I am supposed to be creating a game in which a random word from a text file is selected. This word is then scrambled and displayed for the user.  The user must then try to guess the original word. When they are done they press Check Answer and whether or not they are correct is displayed. This is my first time doing anything in C# (I'm used to Java) so I would greatly appreciate basic explanations if applicable. I've gotten most of the program written however when the scrambled word is displayed it doesn't show the entire scrambled word, only about 3 letters and sometimes the same 3 letters for each word. I've looked over my code and have had trouble finding what is wrong. I've done some quick testing and I know that the file is being read in and the origWords[] array does have a full word stored in it. This leads me to believe that the problem is within the jumbleWords() method. I appreciate any and all help.

EDIT: I cut the code down to what I believe the problem area to be.

```
private string jumbleWords(String origWord)
{
    // converts word to char array
    char [] charArray = origWord.ToCharArray();  
    // creates bool array with length of charArray
    bool [] letterCheck = new bool [charArray.Length];    
    for (int i = 0; i < letterCheck.Length; i++)
    { 
        letterCheck[i] = false;
    }

    Random letterAssign = new Random();
    string jumble = null;

    for (int index = 0; index < charArray.Length; index++)  //jumbling     of word
    {
        // picks random letter (number position of array)        
        int letterChosen = letterAssign.Next(charArray.Length);   
        if (letterCheck[letterChosen] == false) //check if letter has been used    
        {
            jumble += charArray[letterChosen];  //adds letter to jumble string
            // changes bool array position to true so it can't be used again        
            letterCheck[letterChosen] = true;   
        }
    }
    return jumble;
}
```

Comment: Look up [Fisher Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) and use that to jumble your word. This isn't a C# language issue, it's a poor selection of algorithm issue.

Comment: *However I went ahead and displayed the entire program.*, that is actually counter-productive. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you believe `jumbleWords` is your problem, then write an MCVE that tests just that function, confirm that it's the problem, and then post just that code. Dumping a whole bunch of code makes it harder for people to help you.

Comment: I cut it down to the problem area. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you check to see if a particular letter has been used, in the case where it *has* been used, you just continue on to the next position. Instead you need to try again until you get a letter that hasn't been used. Easiest way is just to decrement your loop variable so it tries the slot again.

Also, your logic for picking the words doesn't have the check to see if the word has been picked - you just choose a random one from the whole file each time so you quite often end up with the same word over and over again.

Comment: I appreciate you input. I understand your second point but I'm not sure how to implement it without a bunch of clunky code.  Could your first point be the problem I have been having? Thank you

Comment: The first point is why you only get a couple of letters for each word. The second point is why you get the same word over and over. To fix the latter, you could probably just read the file once and use the same procedure to pick words that you used to pick letters (once you fix the problem in the first point, obviously)

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I think it may work but now I'm getting an Exception error on this portion.                                                                                                           char [] charArray = origWord.ToCharArray();

Comment: You're probably best off posting another question about that if you're still stuck, since it would be a completely different topic.